# Help explain と in this sentence

Tags: grammar, particle-と, negation

私も行かないと。

I understood it as "I also won't go." But according to [Tae Kim's guide](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/define) and Google Translate it is read as "I have to go too." Why is that? I assume と has something to do with it since removing it gives me what I understood of it in the first place or so sayeth Google Translate.

For the full context:

Ａ：行かなくてもいいよ。

Ｂ：だって、みんな行くって。私も行かないと。

Yeah. What I understood of it does not make sense in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context, I would interperet といけない to mean "I must" (because there is something you must do elsewhere etc or you have some obligation to fulfil).

So: 私も行かないと = I must also go.

私も行かないと is actually a contraction of 私も行かない**といけない** or 私も行かない**といけません**.

For example:

私も戻らないと → 私も戻らないといけません

Tae-Kim explains it here (better than me!): http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/must

Comment: You're right. Can't believe I missed that. Thanks.